# Permutations Question: Letter Arrangements with Restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many arrangements can be made of the letters in the word PHOTOGRAPH?

What I did was, $8P5$ to find the number of arrangements between the two H's, then multiplied by 4! because the 5 letters and two H's act as one unit. Is this correct?

Thanks

Comment: You have not stated any restrictions.  However, you seem to be assuming that there are exactly five letters between the two Hs.

Comment: What do you mean as a restriction? Is it 'same letters are not distinguishable', which means e.g. swapping O with T makes a new permutation, whilst swapping O with O, or H with H, does not?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure if your method is correct—it may be!

But an alternative to doing the same question would be to count the number of letters in the word—in this case, $10$—and then also count the number of times a particular letter repeats itself—in this case, “P” comes twice, “H” comes twice, and “O” comes twice as well.

Now all you need to do is divide $10$! by $2!\cdot 2!\cdot 2!$, which gives you $45360$ as the answer.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

So we have the word "PHOTOGRAPH", Which has 2 - "P", 2 - "O" and 2 - "H",
given that we need to place the words such that two H's retain, we can do something like this, *H _ _ _ _ _ H*
now, we can fill the 5 spaces with 5 letters but those 5 letters exclude the two H's but include the P's and O's so the no:of ways to arrange that 5 letters would be $$\frac{5!}{2!*2!}$$, now this and The H's can be arranged in 2 ways so $$2 *\frac{5!}{2!*2!}$$ is a unit.

So we now have total 4 units and 4 spots, so 4! ways.

the final answer would be = $$\frac{5!}{2!*2!}* 4! * 2! = 1440 ways $$

Comment: Why are you assuming that there are five letters between the two Hs?  It does not say that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is just

- distingush *every single letter*,
- consider all possible permutations, and then
- discard duplicates.

So, replace the word with $PHOToGRAph$, calculate $10!$ possible permutations and then reduce it to $\dfrac{10!}{2!\cdot 2!\cdot 2!}$ due to indistinguishable permutations of two $O$'s, of two $P$'s and of two $H$'s.